# Cassandra Opscenter repair causes Null Pointer Exception

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

Got a four node apache cassandra cluster (2.1) with DataStax opscenter 5.0.1 running. Everything's running smoothly...I can restart nodes from opscenter. However, if I try to run a repair on a node from the Opscenter UI, I get the following:

"Error during repair on [hostname]: java.lang.NullPointerException:"

I can ssh into the node and run nodetool repair without problems.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opscenter 5.0 doesn’t support managing Cassandra 2.1 clusters yet, but that’ll change after 5.1 gets released.